# Accessing the model instance in validation messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `Events` to which each `User` can be invited once:

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to  :event
  belongs_to  :user

  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id,
                          scope: :event_id,
                          message: "has already been invited"
end
```

I would like to include the users' name in the error message, something to the effect of

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id,
                         scope: :event_id,
                         message: ->(error, values) { "#{user.firstname} has already been invited" }
```

However I cannot access the model instance from within the lambda. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: did you try `User.find(values[:user_id]).firstname` ?

Comment: @phoet that would work, but I would prefer to avoid the second database query.

Comment: If you can do what @phoet wrote what stops you from `values[:firstname]`?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel `values` only contains the ID.

Comment: Another guess: `validates_uniqueness_of :user, ...`?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel hot diggity: using full associations for uniqueness checks used to be not possible, but as it turns out that has actually been fixed since [this commit](https://github.com/LaunchWare/rails/commit/3b5fbafab014325bdd42a7cae867ee5c92bc3298). If you care to add an answer, I would be glad to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: It's not that new! ;) I was pretty sure I used it somewhere, but was to lazy to check it before answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user, 
                        scope: :event,
                        message: ->(error, values) { "#{values[:user].firstname} has already been invited" }
```

as per [this Rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4321), however there was some regression in 3.2, so check if this works with your version.